# How to cast QTableWidgetItem to custom child class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, casting, qobject

I'm trying to cast a `QTableWidgetItem` into a child class.  I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
(Parent -> Child)
QTableWidgetItem -> SortableTableWidgetItem -> EnhancedTableWidgetItem
```

or

`class SortableTableWidgetItem : public QTableWidgetItem`

`class EnhancedTableWidgetItem : public SortableTableWidgetItem`

For the most part, I use the items as `QTableWidgetItem`s because that code is already written and shouldn't change.  However in some instances I need to access data in the `EnhancedTableWidgetItem` after being given a pointer to `QTableWidgetItem` (which I know is an `EnhancedTableWidgetItem` because I constructed the object and passed it to the calling code initially).  I have tried casting like this:

```
QTableWidgetItem item = getItem();

// This fails to compile saying "error: no matching function for call to ‘qobject_cast(QTableWidgetItem*)’"
EnhancedTableWidgetItem *eItem = qobject_cast<EnhancedTableWidgetItem*>( item );

// This also fails to compile and says: "error: invalid conversion from ‘QTableWidgetItem*’ to ‘EnhancedTableWidgetItem*’"
EnhancedTableWidgetItem *eItem = dynamic_cast<EnhancedTableWidgetItem*>( item );
```

I come from the Java world where this is perfectly legal and is done all the time.  Why can't I cast the base class pointer into a child class pointer?  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qobject_cast` is only for a class which inherit from `QObject`. If `item` is really of your custom type then use dynamic cast

```
EnhancedTableWidgetItem* eItem = dynamic_cast<EnhancedTableWidgetItem*>( item );
```

Nevermind. ***you are casting an object to a pointer.*** It will not work. Still, what I previously said still apply

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed the pointer in the initial post.  It's in the code though.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: it is an undefined behavior to cast the superclass into the subclass if you are not using pointers

Answer (score 1):

You're getting mixed up with pointers and values. I think your `getItem()` should not return value (copy), it should return a pointer, so have this:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = getItem(); // getItem() returns pointer
auto eItem = dynamic_cast<EnhancedTableWidgetItem*>( item );
```

(Using `auto` of C++11 above, which is much nicer, but if you're stuck with older compiler, then use `EnhancedTableWidgetItem*` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

QTableWidgetItem is not derived from QObject, thus it cannot use qobject_cast<>.